# Sabre Travel REST service

Tags: php, rest, soap, sabre, sabredav

Had a look at their documentation and it seems that in PHP, we cant do all request via the REST service.

For example:

I could fetch flights by REST (Instaflights Search)

But when I want to book something, I need to jump into SOAP (Book Air Segment)

I would prefer to do everything in REST rather than SOAP or half and half.

Is this the right way to create a booking engine? Or I am missing something?

Comment: Are you asking if their a Sabre REST Booking APIs available, like for SOAP?

Comment: yep, I dont see a way to book with the REST API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sabre is working on developing REST Booking API. At this moment only available using SOAP technology.

Answer (score 1):

Instaflights is available on REST only, not SOAP. But Pnr creation will have to be on SOAP only, for now.